# Socket Programming - Client not receiving message from server

Tags: python, sockets

I got this as a client:

```
from socket import socket

conn = socket()
conn.connect(('localhost', 9000))
conn.send('dsa')
print conn.recv(1024)
```

and this as a server:

```
from SocketServer import TCPServer, BaseRequestHandler
class EchoHandler(BaseRequestHandler): 
    def handle(self):
        print 'dsa'
        message = self.request.recv(1024) 
        self.request.send(message)


echoServer = TCPServer(('localhost', 9000), EchoHandler) 
echoServer.serve_forever()
```

However the `print conn.recv(1024)` enters an infinite loop and I don't receive anything. Any thoughts?

EDIT: 
     Forgot to mention that the print statement in the handle method is not executed

Comment: Did the server crash?

Comment: I tried it with Python 2.7.6 and it works fine. I first start the server. Every time I run the client both server and client prints "dsa". Client quits and server still runs. Is this what you want? What Python version do you use?

Comment: I've tested it with python 2.7.5 and Windows Vista and the client prints 'dsa' and terminates

Comment: 2.7.8 on OS X Mavericks

Comment: Do you have any firewall configured?

Comment: What makes you think you have an infinite loop if you don't receive anything? I suggest you add some more print statements to track it better. For example print 'Got: ' + conn.recv(1024). Try other ports also. It would help if you also listed the exact steps you take and exact result.

Comment: @rafalopez i ran similar code from a book yesterday and it worked perfectly, so I dont think its the firewall, and also its turned off

Comment: @Rein on every other port i get [Errno 61] connection refused

Comment: Just to make sure: Did you change port on both server and client (they must be the same)?

Comment: Yes, but no results. In the end i gave up and created the server as an instance of socket() from the socket module instead of TCPServer from the SocketServer...